# How can I remove all PPA?

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I noticed that

```
sudo apt-get update
```

takes longer and longer, because i used  several

```
sudo apt-add-repository xxx
```

it seems like non ubuntu repositories are not as fast or dont have as much bandwith as the default ones.

How can i reset the repositories to the default ones, removing all the ones added by me? (not to worry, if ever need any of them i can add them later)

Comment: No. It is not quite duplicate.

Comment: Check http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/remove-ppa-repositories-via-command.html about how to use ppa-purge.

Comment: It is a duplicate of that though ^^

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To delete and purge all PPAs:

The `ppa-purge` removes the PPA and tries to replace the installed packages with the version of the Officially Ubuntu Repositories

1. Install `ppa-purge`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   ```
2. List the commands to be used with the command below. This command **does nothing than print** the commands to be used in the next step

   ```
   find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | \
       while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {print "sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5}' "$file"; done
   ```
3. **Check the previous output** and if all is ok, fire the purge-commands by the command below

   ```
   find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | \
       while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {system("sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5)}' "$file"; done
   ```

---

Sample output

```
% find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /launchpad/ {print "sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5}' "$file"; done
sudo ppa-purge ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bugs-launchpad-net-falkensweb/cool-retro-term
sudo ppa-purge ppa:andreas-boettger/gmusicbrowser-art
sudo ppa-purge ppa:yorba/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo ppa-purge ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo ppa-purge ppa:andreas-boettger/private
sudo ppa-purge ppa:snappy-dev/beta
sudo ppa-purge ppa:diesch/testing
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo ppa-purge ppa:musicbrainz-developers/stable
sudo ppa-purge ppa:latexila/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gencfsm/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo ppa-purge ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:stackapplet-dev/stackapplet
sudo ppa-purge ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/unstable
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo ppa-purge ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
sudo ppa-purge ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo ppa-purge ppa:numix/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:dreibh/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:saiarcot895/flightgear
sudo ppa-purge ppa:andreas-boettger/gmusicbrowser-daily
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Comment: There is no need to add a PPA itself for ppa-purge, it's already on Official Repos.

Comment: Dear **downvoter**, some constructive critic would be great.

Comment: This is really useful before 'sudo apt dist-upgrade'!!!
I saved all in a file and replaced ppa-purge with add-apt-repository to make a script to use after dist-upgrade!

Comment: **Minor improvement:** in step 3., the `-y` option should be passed to `ppa-purge` to ensure that previously installed PPA packages are properly downgraded. Failing to pass this option commonly results in errors resembling `Warning:  Something went wrong, packages may not have been reverted`. (*Your mileage may vary.*)

Comment: for me it didn't work until i removed them from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with this script `find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 |     while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {system("sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/"$4"-ubuntu-"$5"-focal.list")}' "$file"; done`

Answer (score 1):

You can use same command with key `--remove` like this:

`sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:<user_name>/<ppa_name>`

And clean them one by one. It's the safe way. Or clean their files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, this way not recommended but working as well.

You can also use package `ppa-purge`. As mentioned [there](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/remove-ppa-repositories-via-command.html).

Comment: It is not `ppa:ppa-name/ppa`, but ppa:<user_name>/<ppa_name>`

Comment: This will neither remove the packages installed by PPA's

Comment: @xangua - this question not about packages removal.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok, it's fixed

Comment: Downvote was not mine. That's probably @xangua. Two good answers are downvoted.

Comment: @Pilot6 it doesn't matter. Wrong example - bad example. Thanks for findings.

Comment: this command is not removing the ppa which are mentioned as "(source code)"

Answer (score -2):

You could try this:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository remove (ppa)
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: wrong syntax, please correct this answer

Comment: and wrong command also

Answer (score -4):

You can do it by running in terminal

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

This will remove all ppa. But this will NOT remove packages installed from ppa.

Comment: something is broken `thenok@thenok-MS-7693 ~ $ sudo apt-get update
Error: No information about packages! (Maybe no deb entries?)
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'`
E: Sub-process returned an error code

Comment: @ThenEnok What do you mean "broken"? What did you do?

Comment: This will not remove the packages installed by all PPA's

Comment: ran the above command and afterwards ran `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Did you type the command by hand or copied it from here? You could have made an error.

Comment: I tested it on my computer and it works OK. You could mistype and spoil someting. Please post output of `history 20`.

Comment: @xangua And? That was not the question.

Comment: @A.B. It's important to focus on what the real problem is, not just the question. This is not internet points, is people helping people.

Comment: @xangua The real problem is slow running of `apt-get update`. And this answer addresses exactly what OP asked.

Comment: @xangua - there is no goal to remove all packages installed by PPA. And there is already answer on askubuntu or even set of same answers.

Comment: You could try this: sudo -i and then gedit /etc/atp/sources.list and delete them you don't need.