# Can't install GIMP on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-center, gimp, 16.10

I have searched "GIMP" on my Ubuntu 16.10(64bit) Ubuntu Software, but it was not there, so i tried to install it with this simple Command :

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

and after typing my password the result was :

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so how can i install gimp on my Ubuntu 16.10 ?

Edit : I've treid to install vlc and i got a similar error but about another package and on the last line it mentioned some of my packages are broken , i'm searching to solve that. As it is maybe visible I'm somewhat new to linux , so i mentioned that similar problem , but i don't know is it really related or not.

Comment: Try with aptitude

Comment: You may follow this link. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/11/how-to-install-gimp-2-8-16-in-ubuntu-16-04-15-10-14-04/

Comment: what do you get back for ' apt-cache policy gimp'

Comment: Candidate: 2.8.18-1
  Version table:
     2.8.18-1 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
     2.8.18-0y3~ppa 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Package

Comment: and @PhilipKirkbride this question is not duplicate of the one you said , i want to install the latest possible stable version of GIMP from every method it can be done , but he just asked about a terminal error.

Comment: I'm not posting that to say you shouldn't have asked this question. I'm tagging it so that other's know whatever solution works for this question (or vise versa) will likely solve the other question as well. It may be that you find a solution and now you'll be able to answer your own question and that other persons.

Comment: Did you already try 'sudo apt-get install libgegl-0.3-0' ?

Comment: yes , that package can't be installed , i checked it.

Comment: That package broken message you got do you also get something similar when you run 'sudo apt-get update'? I think I've had a similar issue before and it related to a PPA that I'd added.  You might want to try something like this http://askubuntu.com/a/646918/135947

But be warned this will remove all the custom PPAs that you added. Then you'll have to re-add what you want and figure out which one was the problem. Hopefully that's what's causing your issue.

Comment: After you remove the PPAs try installing vlc or gimp and let me know if you still have the same problem.

Comment: I removed PPAs , but result is the same , for vlc its : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.