# Unable to install cURL on Ubuntu 20.04 due to dependency issues

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dependencies, curl

I use Ubuntu 20.04.1 and trying to install cURL. When I run `sudo apt install curl` in the terminal I get an error of:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: curl : Depends: libcurl4 (= 7.68.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried to follow this [slightly similar solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099385/1098549) unsuccessfully.
This is the screenshot of the error as it appears in my computer:

[image: screenshot of my error]

Output of `apt-cache policy curl libcurl4`:

```
curl: 
  Installed: (none) 
  Candidate: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2 
  Version table: 
     7.68.0-1ubuntu2 500
     500 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libcurl4:
  Installed: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2
  Version table: 
 *** 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 
     7.68.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You must have done something strange prior to this... here is my 20.04, and curl untouched / via upgrade (if that has happened):   
`$ curl --version` -> `7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2` => Did you `apt get uninstall` it?

Comment: `$ dpkg --list | grep libcurl` => libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 and libcurl4:amd64 both with version `7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2` (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Comment: @Kulfy True. Here is the new output after running you command. 
curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     7.68.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libcurl4:
  Installed: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2
  Version table:
 *** 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.68.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

Comment: @Kulfy See the image of the output here: https://slack-files.com/T98GZSJPR-F01FCCLSZPU-cadaad34a2

Comment: @Hannu I have run the command dpkg --list | grep libcurl - see this image of what I get https://slack-files.com/T98GZSJPR-F01EXLFS571-75f602694e    
That:
ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64                      7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1                    amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libcurl4:amd64                             7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2                    amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1134120/289138 <- might this work!?

Comment: @Hannu I have apache2 in my computer, is there a way to remove libcurl14 alone, because I wouldn't love to unistall my apache server. When I run sudo apt remove libcurl4 I get this : https://slack-files.com/T98GZSJPR-F01FJJBC36G-8c34af6396

Comment: @Hannu That: The following packages will be REMOVED: apache2 apache2-bin atom libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.4 libcurl4

Comment: @Hannu Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have libcurl4 from `focal-updates` while APT is trying to install cURL from `focal` since you don't have `focal-updates` updates enabled (anymore?). At this point you have 2 options. Either enable `focal-updates` repository or install libcurl4 from `focal`.

1. To enable focal-updates, run

   ```
   echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   Once done, run `sudo apt update` and retry installing cURL.
2. To install libcurl4 from focal, simply run

   ```
   sudo apt install libcurl4=7.68.0-1ubuntu2
   ```

   Retry installing cURL.

The later one might not work if you have packages dependent on installed libcurl4, i.e., version 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2.

Comment: Thankyou bro it worked !!!!

Comment: It is surprising a standard tool like curl is so delicate.  I even tried building it from source and still get errors.

Answer (score 1):

Please run this command in terminal

```
sudo snap install curl  # version 7.84.0
```

or

```
sudo apt  install curl  # version 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13
```

Comment: snap works (8.1) , apt is still outdated to 7.88