# Can't update Ubuntu 16 to 18

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.10-x86_64-linode132 x86_64)
Try to update to 18 but get some errors. When i make `do-release-upgrade` i get

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> This was likely caused by:
>   * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge package to remove software from a
>   Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade again.
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command
>   'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.If you want to
>   investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade'
>   will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at
>   'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

> Broken systemd-sysv:i386 Conflicts on systemd-shim [ i386 ] <
>   9-1bzr4ubuntu1 > ( admin ) Broken systemd-sysv:i386 Conflicts on
>   upstart-sysv [ i386 ] < 1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1 > ( admin ) Broken
>   systemd:i386 Conflicts on upstart [ i386 ] < 1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1 > (
>   admin ) Broken imagemagick-6-common:i386 Breaks on
>   libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ i386 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (<
>   8:6.9.6.2+dfsg-3~) Broken perl:i386 Depends on perl-modules-5.26 [
>   i386 ] < none -> 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 > ( perl ) (>= 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3)
>   Broken libperl5.26:i386 Depends on perl-modules-5.26 [ i386 ] < none
>   -> 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 > ( perl ) (>= 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3) Broken libdpkg-perl:i386 Depends on perl [ i386 ] < none -> 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
>
> > ( perl ) Broken dpkg-dev:i386 Depends on perl:any [ any ] < none ->  > ( none ) Broken poppler-data:i386 Breaks on gs-cjk-resource [ i386 ] < 1.20100103-3 > ( text ) (<= 1.20100103-3) Broken
> >     libalgorithm-merge-perl:i386 Depends on perl [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 > ( perl ) Broken libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:i386 Depends on perl [ i386 ] < none -> 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 > ( perl ) (>=
> >     5.26.1-4) Broken libfile-fcntllock-perl:i386 Depends on perl [ i386 ] < none -> 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 > ( perl ) (>= 5.26.0-4) Broken
> >     libalgorithm-diff-perl:i386 Depends on perl [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 > ( perl ) Broken pkg-config:i386 Depends on dpkg-dev [ i386 ] < none -> 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3 > ( utils ) Broken
> >     build-essential:i386 Depends on dpkg-dev [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3 > ( utils ) (>= 1.17.11) Broken libdbus-1-dev:i386 Depends on pkg-config [ i386 ] < none -> 0.29.1-0ubuntu2 > ( devel )
> >     Broken libglib2.0-dev:i386 Depends on libpcre3-dev [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     2:8.39-9 > ( libdevel ) (>= 1:8.31) Broken python-dbus-dev:i386
> >     Depends on libdbus-1-dev [ i386 ] < none -> 1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1 > (
> >     libdevel ) (>= 1.6) Broken libharfbuzz-dev:i386 Depends on
> >     libglib2.0-dev [ i386 ] < none -> 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 > ( libdevel
> >     ) (>= 2.19.1) Broken libmagickwand-6.q16-2:i386 Depends on
> >     libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ i386 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>=
> >     8:6.8.9.9) Broken libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:i386 Depends on
> >     libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ i386 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>=
> >     8:6.8.9.9) Broken python3-zope.hookable:i386 Depends on python3 [ i386
> >     ] < 3.5.1-3 -> 3.6.7-1~18.04 > ( python ) (< 3.6) Broken
> >     libicu-le-hb-dev:i386 Depends on libharfbuzz-dev [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     1.7.2-1ubuntu1 > ( libdevel ) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
> >     Broken icu-devtools:i386 Breaks on libicu-dev [ i386 ] <
> >     55.1-7ubuntu0.5 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3.1) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel ) Broken icu-devtools:i386 Breaks on libicu-dev [ i386 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.5 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel
> >     ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3.1) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on
> >     libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
> >     Broken icu-devtools:i386 Breaks on libicu-dev [ i386 ] <
> >     55.1-7ubuntu0.5 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3.1) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel ) Broken icu-devtools:i386 Breaks on libicu-dev [ i386 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.5 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel
> >     ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3.1) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on
> >     libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
> >     Broken icu-devtools:i386 Breaks on libicu-dev [ i386 ] <
> >     55.1-7ubuntu0.5 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3.1) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel ) Broken icu-devtools:i386 Breaks on libicu-dev [ i386 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.5 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel
> >     ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3.1) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on
> >     libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
> >     Broken icu-devtools:i386 Breaks on libicu-dev [ i386 ] <
> >     55.1-7ubuntu0.5 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3.1) Broken libicu-dev:i386 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ i386 ] < none ->
> >     1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )

What i should do with it? Please help

Comment: What of this don't you understand? "This was likely caused by: * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade again."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: There are two supported kernels for Ubuntu 16.04, neither is 5.4, so your first line shows you're not using a supported kernel (thus that package itself may stop upgrade) so I don't need to go beyond a few words into your description for the first obvious possible blocking package.  To make it work 3rd party packages should be removed (eg. PPA's) plus packages intended for later releases etc...)

Comment: @pLumo, sorry but realy can't get it. I removed all PPA by this method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/646884/how-can-i-remove-all-ppa 
if i make sudo ls `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
there are no any files with PPA_XXX

Comment: And now if make `do-release-upgrade` i get
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.If
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

Comment: /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log - http://prntscr.com/rro1p2

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this issue , if you want to upgrade but can't:

**Way 1**

Step 1 : open [Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4NRj.png).

Step 2 : change `Download from` to [Main Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jweWP.png)

Step 3 : open Terminal (`ctlr + alt + t`) then `sudo apt-get update` , then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

**Way 2 Remove PPA**

Step 1 : open [Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4NRj.png).

Step 2 : go to Other Software tab and choose the desire PPA from the list. Afterwards click on [Remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BjQ2.jpg) to remove it.

*OR*

You can remove it using terminal : `sudo apt-add-repository -r PPA_Name/ppa`

**Way 3 :**

[Read This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

also try to use this commands , may it help: `sudo apt clean` , `sudo apt autoclean` , `sudo apt autoremove`.