# Cant update ubuntu 18.04, I think the problem is in sources.list file

Tags: 18.04, apt, xubuntu, update-manager

I Can't Update Ubuntu 18.04, I think the problem is in sources.list file, But i cant resolve it;

`sudo apt-get update` doesn't work,

Here's the result of sudo apt-get update :

```
brucewayne@Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                           
Hit:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                
Get:4 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease [3,956 B]                               
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                  
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                   
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                  
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                         
Err:4 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease                                         
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG CDFB5FA52007B954 Metasploit <metasploit@rapid7.com>
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                            
Err:9 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease                                                                           
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
Hit:12 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                          
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                              
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:15 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease                                         
Hit:18 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                         
Reading package lists... Done 
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG CDFB5FA52007B954 Metasploit <metasploit@rapid7.com>
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (apps/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target Packages (apps/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target Packages (apps/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target Translations (apps/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target Translations (apps/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (apps/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (apps/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (apps/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (apps/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target CNF (apps/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target CNF (apps/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
W: Target Packages (apps/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target Packages (apps/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target Packages (apps/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target Translations (apps/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target Translations (apps/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (apps/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (apps/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (apps/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (apps/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target CNF (apps/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
W: Target CNF (apps/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:3
```

Comment: Yes, I do think that your sources could be a problem. You should remove all the non-Canonical sources and PPAs prior to the attempted upgrade.  Some may not be supported in the new version at all.  To be honest I'm surprised your system is functional with this sources list. You have sources from at least three different distros. Adding tons of sources/PPAs is a terribly messy way to install unofficial software compared to snap/flatpak/docker/appimage.  You may also want to read: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for

Comment: "You should remove all the non-Canonical sources and PPAs prior to the attempted upgrade" how do i do this?. A Link will be of great help. Thanks in advance!

Does this looks an okay way of going about this? : https://askubuntu.com/questions/646884/how-can-i-remove-all-ppa

Comment: @RaviJha yeah you can follow [this answer from duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/26246)  you mention

Comment: You must have added these sources to begin with. Generally the process to remove them is the opposite of how you added them. Ex. If you manually added items to the list, manually remove them.  But this sources list is such a mess, are you sure you shouldn't just do a clean install?  Wouldn't it be faster and more reliable than trying to upgrade from this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed the metasploit problem

```
sudo wget -O - http://apt.metasploit.com/metasploit-framework.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update
```