# unknown icons under real icons in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons

[image: icons]

After following the commands here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1288767/806813
and doing `sudo apt-get purge` for many packages, I ended up with the above issue.
What did I purge that I should not have and how can I fix this?

Edit: it is gone now after a reboot.  I have never installed Dash Dock nor anything else related to the dock.

Comment: What dock is that? It looks like you have two docks on top of each other based on the way the background colour changes. The icons underneath are the places icons. Try moving the dock to another edge and see if it exposes the one below so you can delete it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I have two docks in Ubuntu desktop (with GNOME 3) after installing Dash to Dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975387/why-do-i-have-two-docks-in-ubuntu-desktop-with-gnome-3-after-installing-dash-t)

Comment: @MarkKirby it is gone now after a reboot.  I don't know why.