# Cannot upgrade ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

Guess it has something to do with some of the packages found in the `main.log` file:

```
2022-09-25 17:32:11,230 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.focal', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2022-09-25 17:32:11,230 INFO uname information: 'Linux TAB-X1C7 5.15.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 16:17:26 UTC 2022 x86_64'
2022-09-25 17:32:12,052 INFO apt version: '2.0.9'
2022-09-25 17:32:12,052 INFO python version: '3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0]'
2022-09-25 17:32:12,058 INFO release-upgrader version '22.04.14' started
2022-09-25 17:32:12,206 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2022-09-25 17:32:12,728 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewGtk3' view
2022-09-25 17:32:12,808 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2022-09-25 17:32:12,842 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2022-09-25 17:32:26,850 DEBUG lsb-release: 'focal'
2022-09-25 17:32:26,851 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2022-09-25 17:32:26,852 DEBUG openCache()
2022-09-25 17:32:26,852 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2022-09-25 17:32:26,852 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2022-09-25 17:32:28,280 DEBUG Comparing 5.11.0-46 with 
2022-09-25 17:32:28,281 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-52 with 5.11.0-46
2022-09-25 17:32:28,282 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.13.0-52
2022-09-25 17:32:28,282 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-48 with 5.15.0-46
2022-09-25 17:32:28,482 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 81027
2022-09-25 17:32:28,483 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2022-09-25 17:32:28,483 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2022-09-25 17:32:28,483 DEBUG depends: 'apt (>= 2.0.4)'
2022-09-25 17:32:28,483 DEBUG checking: '[('apt', '2.0.4', '>=')]' 
2022-09-25 17:32:28,483 DEBUG depends: 'libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.0.4)'
2022-09-25 17:32:28,483 DEBUG checking: '[('libapt-pkg6.0', '2.0.4', '>=')]' 
2022-09-25 17:32:28,486 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2022-09-25 17:32:48,254 DEBUG openCache()
2022-09-25 17:32:49,693 DEBUG Comparing 5.11.0-46 with 
2022-09-25 17:32:49,695 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-52 with 5.11.0-46
2022-09-25 17:32:49,695 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.13.0-52
2022-09-25 17:32:49,695 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-48 with 5.15.0-46
2022-09-25 17:32:49,912 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 81027
2022-09-25 17:32:49,912 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2022-09-25 17:32:49,912 DEBUG quirks: running jammyPostInitialUpdate
2022-09-25 17:32:49,912 DEBUG running Quirks.jammyPostInitialUpdate
2022-09-25 17:32:50,861 DEBUG running Quirks._test_and_fix_missing_nvidia_metapackage
2022-09-25 17:32:55,604 DEBUG No autoremovable libnvidia-gl found, exiting.
2022-09-25 17:32:58,024 DEBUG Snap core20 is installed
2022-09-25 17:32:58,785 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-38-2004 is installed
2022-09-25 17:32:58,786 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-38-2004 is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:32:59,157 DEBUG Snap gtk-common-themes is installed
2022-09-25 17:32:59,551 DEBUG Snap snap-store is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:00,258 DEBUG Snap bare is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:00,258 DEBUG Snap bare is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:00,633 DEBUG Snap bitwarden is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:00,633 DEBUG Snap bitwarden is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:01,050 DEBUG Snap brave is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:01,050 DEBUG Snap brave is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:01,475 DEBUG Snap canonical-livepatch is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:01,475 DEBUG Snap canonical-livepatch is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:01,858 DEBUG Snap chromium is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:01,859 DEBUG Snap chromium is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:02,244 DEBUG Snap core is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:02,244 DEBUG Snap core is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:02,639 DEBUG Snap core18 is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:02,640 DEBUG Snap core18 is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:03,003 DEBUG Snap core22 is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:03,004 DEBUG Snap core22 is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:03,393 DEBUG Snap discord is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:03,393 DEBUG Snap discord is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:03,782 DEBUG Snap exercism is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:03,782 DEBUG Snap exercism is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:04,173 DEBUG Snap flutter is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:04,173 DEBUG Snap flutter is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:04,566 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-28-1804 is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:04,566 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-28-1804 is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:04,980 DEBUG Snap gnome-42-2204 is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:04,980 DEBUG Snap gnome-42-2204 is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:05,378 DEBUG Snap google-cloud-sdk is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:05,379 DEBUG Snap google-cloud-sdk is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:05,768 DEBUG Snap heroku is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:05,768 DEBUG Snap heroku is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:06,165 DEBUG Snap httpie is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:06,165 DEBUG Snap httpie is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:06,569 DEBUG Snap intellij-idea-educational is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:06,570 DEBUG Snap intellij-idea-educational is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:06,946 DEBUG Snap iptvnator is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:06,947 DEBUG Snap iptvnator is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:07,323 DEBUG Snap kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20 is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:07,324 DEBUG Snap kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20 is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:07,698 DEBUG Snap kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20 is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:07,699 DEBUG Snap kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20 is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:08,070 DEBUG Snap okular is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:08,071 DEBUG Snap okular is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:08,464 DEBUG Snap pdftk is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:08,465 DEBUG Snap pdftk is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:08,872 DEBUG Snap remmina is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:08,872 DEBUG Snap remmina is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:09,262 DEBUG Snap skype is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:09,262 DEBUG Snap skype is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:09,656 DEBUG Snap slack is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:09,656 DEBUG Snap slack is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:10,047 DEBUG Snap snapd is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:10,048 DEBUG Snap snapd is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:10,446 DEBUG Snap sublime-text is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:10,447 DEBUG Snap sublime-text is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:10,850 DEBUG Snap vlc is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:10,851 DEBUG Snap vlc is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:11,236 DEBUG Snap youtube-music-desktop-app is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:11,236 DEBUG Snap youtube-music-desktop-app is not tracking the release channel
2022-09-25 17:33:11,625 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-34-1804 is installed
2022-09-25 17:33:11,726 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-34-1804 is being used by slack. Switching it to stable track
2022-09-25 17:33:16,902 DEBUG MetaPkgs: ubuntu-desktop
2022-09-25 17:33:26,739 DEBUG Foreign: acpi-call-dkms aspnetcore-runtime-5.0 aspnetcore-runtime-6.0 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-5.0 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-6.0 brave-browser brave-keyring code containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-scan-plugin dotnet-apphost-pack-5.0 dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0 dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-5.0 dotnet-hostfxr-6.0 dotnet-runtime-5.0 dotnet-runtime-6.0 dotnet-runtime-deps-5.0 dotnet-runtime-deps-6.0 dotnet-sdk-5.0 dotnet-sdk-6.0 dotnet-targeting-pack-5.0 dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0 dropbox google-chrome-stable ibus-bamboo indicator-stickynotes keybase kodi kodi-bin kodi-inputstream-adaptive kodi-inputstream-ffmpegdirect kodi-inputstream-rtmp kodi-peripheral-joystick kodi-pvr-iptvsimple libcdio19 libiso9660-11 libodbc1 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib libshairplay0 libudfread0 microsoft-edge-stable mongodb-database-tools mongodb-mongosh mongodb-org mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1 numix-icon-theme numix-icon-theme-circle odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 packages-microsoft-prod papirus-icon-theme python3.10 python3.10-minimal python3.9 python3.9-minimal signal-desktop slimbookbattery slimbookintelcontroller spotify-client surfshark-release surfshark-vpn teams teamviewer tlp tlp-rdw vivaldi-stable
2022-09-25 17:33:26,739 DEBUG Obsolete: beid-mozilla-extension beid-mozilla-webext eid-archive eid-mw eid-viewer hypnotix libbeidpkcs11-0 libbeidpkcs11-bin libeidviewer0 openjdk-14-jdk openjdk-14-jdk-headless openjdk-14-jre openjdk-14-jre-headless stremio toggldesktop viber virtualbox-6.1 webex zoom
2022-09-25 17:33:26,748 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2022-09-25 17:33:26,774 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2022-09-25 17:33:26,774 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2022-09-25 17:33:26,774 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2022-09-25 17:33:26,780 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2022-09-25 17:33:26,787 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted'
2022-09-25 17:33:26,787 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
2022-09-25 17:33:26,787 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release
2022-09-25 17:33:26,787 DEBUG s='http' n='archive.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release' q='' f=''
2022-09-25 17:33:27,312 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,313 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,314 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,315 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2022-09-25 17:33:27,315 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,317 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,317 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,318 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,319 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,320 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,320 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,322 DEBUG entry '# deb https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,322 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,324 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,324 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,326 DEBUG entry '# deb http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,326 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,327 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,327 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/ stable main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,329 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,329 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,331 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,331 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,333 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,333 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,334 DEBUG entry '# deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,334 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,336 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,336 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,338 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,338 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,339 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,339 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,341 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,341 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,343 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,343 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,345 DEBUG entry '# deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,345 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freetuxtv/freetuxtv/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,346 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freetuxtv/freetuxtv/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,346 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,348 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,348 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,350 DEBUG entry '# deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,350 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,351 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,351 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bamboo-engine/ibus-bamboo/ubuntu focal main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,353 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bamboo-engine/ibus-bamboo/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:27,353 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main'
2022-09-25 17:33:27,355 DEBUG entry '# deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2022-09-25 17:33:39,772 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2022-09-25 17:35:05,387 DEBUG openCache()
2022-09-25 17:35:05,842 DEBUG Comparing 5.11.0-46 with 
2022-09-25 17:35:05,843 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-52 with 5.11.0-46
2022-09-25 17:35:05,843 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.13.0-52
2022-09-25 17:35:05,843 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-48 with 5.15.0-46
2022-09-25 17:35:05,914 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 74526
2022-09-25 17:35:05,914 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2022-09-25 17:35:05,915 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-25 17:35:05,915 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-25 17:35:06,954 DEBUG Running KeepInstalledSection rules
2022-09-25 17:35:07,313 DEBUG Kernel uname: '5.15.0-48-generic' 
2022-09-25 17:35:07,322 DEBUG nvidiaUpdate()
2022-09-25 17:35:07,872 INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new
2022-09-25 17:35:07,872 DEBUG Removing 'gnome-cups-manager' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-25 17:35:07,872 DEBUG Removing 'powermanagement-interface' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-25 17:35:07,872 DEBUG Removing 'deskbar-applet' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-25 17:35:07,872 DEBUG Removing 'nautilus-cd-burner' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-25 17:35:07,872 DEBUG quirks: running PostDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-25 17:35:07,873 DEBUG running Quirks.PostDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-25 17:35:07,978 DEBUG Comparing 5.11.0-46 with 
2022-09-25 17:35:07,978 DEBUG Comparing 5.13.0-52 with 5.11.0-46
2022-09-25 17:35:07,979 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.13.0-52
2022-09-25 17:35:07,979 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-48 with 5.15.0-46
2022-09-25 17:35:08,036 INFO installing linux metapackage: linux-generic
2022-09-25 17:35:08,036 DEBUG Installing 'linux-generic' (linux metapackage may have been accidentally uninstalled)
2022-09-25 17:35:08,060 DEBUG Marking 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade
2022-09-25 17:35:08,217 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
```

or the `apt.log`, with a lot of "broken" stuff:

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 38
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 38
Investigating (0) libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 < 1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 -> 1.72.0-1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 Breaks on python-gi:amd64 < 3.36.0-1 @ii mK > (< 3.42.0-1+b1)
  Considering python-gi:amd64 -2 as a solution to libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 171
  Added python-gi:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 via remove of python-gi:amd64
  MarkDelete python-gi:amd64 < 3.36.0-1 @ii mK > FU=0
Investigating (0) libnode72:amd64 < none -> 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libnode72:amd64 Breaks on libnode64:amd64 < 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1 @ii mK >
  Considering libnode64:amd64 -3 as a solution to libnode72:amd64 87
  Added libnode64:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libnode72:amd64 via remove of libnode64:amd64
  MarkDelete libnode64:amd64 < 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1 @ii mK > FU=0
Investigating (0) gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 < 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.6 @ii mK > (< 21.04)
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 -3 as a solution to gnome-shell:amd64 54
  Added gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-shell:amd64 via remove of gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64
  MarkDelete gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 < 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.6 @ii mK > FU=0
Investigating (0) gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Breaks on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mK > (< 3.37)
  Considering libmutter-6-0:amd64 -2 as a solution to gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 48
  Added libmutter-6-0:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 via remove of libmutter-6-0:amd64
  MarkDelete libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mK > FU=0
Investigating (0) fuse3:amd64 < none -> 3.10.5-1build1 @un uN Ib >
Broken fuse3:amd64 Breaks on fuse:amd64 < 2.9.9-3 -> 2.9.9-5ubuntu3 @ii umU >
  Considering fuse:amd64 4 as a solution to fuse3:amd64 25
  Added fuse:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 2.9.9-3 for fuse but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Fixing fuse3:amd64 via remove of fuse:amd64
  MarkDelete fuse:amd64 < 2.9.9-3 -> 2.9.9-5ubuntu3 @ii umU > FU=0
Investigating (0) libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 < 0.5.4-2 -> 0.5.90-7ubuntu2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 Conflicts on libappindicator3-1:amd64 < 12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1 -> 12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umU >
  Considering libappindicator3-1:amd64 2 as a solution to libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 13
  Added libappindicator3-1:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1 for libappindicator3-1 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Fixing libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 via remove of libappindicator3-1:amd64
  MarkDelete libappindicator3-1:amd64 < 12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1 -> 12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > FU=0
Investigating (0) python3-uno:amd64 < 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 -> 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
  Considering libpython3.10:amd64 0 as a solution to python3-uno:amd64 13
  MarkKeep python3-uno:amd64 < 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 -> 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing python3-uno:amd64 rather than change libpython3.10:amd64
  MarkDelete python3-uno:amd64 < 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 -> 5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python3-pyqt5:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
  Considering libpython3.10:amd64 0 as a solution to python3-pyqt5:amd64 9
  MarkKeep python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 -> 5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing python3-pyqt5:amd64 rather than change libpython3.10:amd64
  MarkDelete python3-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 | 5.15.6+dfsg-1ubuntu3 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 < 1.26.0-2 -> 1.32.0-1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
  Considering libpython3.10:amd64 0 as a solution to libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 9
  MarkKeep libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 < 1.26.0-2 -> 1.32.0-1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 rather than change libpython3.10:amd64
Investigating (0) vim:amd64 < 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.9 -> 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken vim:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
  Considering libpython3.10:amd64 0 as a solution to vim:amd64 8
  MarkKeep vim:amd64 < 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.9 -> 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Removing vim:amd64 rather than change libpython3.10:amd64
  MarkDelete vim:amd64 < 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.9 | 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umH Ib > FU=0
...
```

Is it possible to do this upgrade without having to resolve every single individual broken package?

Comment: Was your system fully updated without throwing errors before you tried to upgrade it?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, it's always fully updated. No errors.

Comment: In that case the problem is almost certainly caused by external ppas you have added to the system. Consider `ppa-purge`ing them and then readd them after the upgrade if required.

Comment: @OrganicMarble like this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/646884/how-can-i-remove-all-ppa/646918.