Software updater giving errors and crashing on Ubuntu 2404
I have been using Ubuntu for about 2 years on a raspberry pi and upgraded to 2404 from 2204 2 months ago on my PC as Windows 10 is ending support. HOWEVER now software updater is not working and neofetch identifies my install as elementaryOS but the software updater says it was unable to read the repositories and asks me to check my internet. I tried using the terminal but it was the same. After trying to change the repository settings it crashed and wont relaunch. IDK how I broke it but I do have have elementary DE installed. I have KDE I tried using discover but it was unable to get system updates I also have an Ubuntu Pro license if that helps to fix this I guess I need help on resetting the repositories to defaults. I am still using Ubuntu and if anyone knows how to revert to original update settings please reply. So far I have

Installed elementaryDE and KDE
Installed Chrome and added the google repository.

When running sudo apt update this happens:
E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Also I do know where the sources are added nvme01p2/etc/apt/sources.list.d so simply deleting the text files that contain URLs and info of elementary repositories will work? And after removing sources how to get software updater to run? About the sources type all elementary sources are stable.

You've likely added an Elementary source to your system without any pinning to protect your system, and thus as apt updates always to the newest packages, and Ubuntu based systems inflate their version numbers so they can safely use Ubuntu repositories; you've now got a FrakenUbuntu system that is actually closer to Elementary.   Your mistake was probably unwisely adding sources to your system, but it appears from your details that you're no longer using a Ubuntu system.  For us to help, you'll need to be specific as to exactly what was done.

This maybe useful - https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian - as whilst it talks about protecting your Debian system rather than a Ubuntu system, as Ubuntu uses the same deb packages, and dpkg and apt package tools; the same applies to Ubuntu too.

Reverse the changes you made; but as you've not said what they were we cannot tell you how.  Firstly I'd sudo apt update and read that output, is ANYTHING from a non-Ubuntu source; particularly look for Elementary sources given your description... If so you must remove all packages from that source and replace them with the Ubuntu packages. If you used a PPA to add them, ppa-purge maybe your fix; but we can't advise as you've not said what you did to your system, thus we don't know what to reverse.

Your added message shows /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources contains an error that needs to be fixed (and as we can't see what's in that file; you should provide a link to where it can be read, or include text of file in your question). If you want help on that; ask in a new question on this site (this question is closed).  If you remove sources though for the Elementary DE (Pantheon) your installed packages will remain & thus changes to your system remain (there are many Elementary PPAs (stable, daily etc) so we cannot be specific with help unless we have details)

For help on PPA-PURGE I suggested, you can look on this site (eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/646884/how-can-i-remove-all-ppa) or in Ubuntu docs (eg. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/third-party-repository-usage mentions it, but details about its use is spread about on many pages with no specific page on use)
